# Why doesn't create record from lightning component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I would like to create record from lightning component.
This component is displayed when button clicked on Record detail page in community.
but, I can't create record.
Here is my code.What is this wrong?

Component

```
<aura:component  controller="StoreChangeController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
<aura:attribute name="contract" type="Contract__c"/>
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.init}" value="{!this}" />

<div class="slds-form-element slds-m-bottom--small slds-is-required">
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractName" label="店舗名" name="contractname" value="{!v.contract.NewAccName__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractFurigana" label="フリガナ" name="contractFurigana" value="{!v.contract.NewAccRuby__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractNname" label="ニックネーム" name="contractNName" value="{!v.contract.NewAccNickname__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractPhone" label="電話番号" name="contractphone" value="{!v.contract.NewAccPhone__c}" type="phone"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractPostal" label="郵便番号" name="contractpostal" value="{!v.contract.NewAccPostalcode__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractState" label="都道府県" name="contractstate" value="{!v.contract.NewAccState__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractCity" label="市区郡" name="contractcity" value="{!v.contract.NewAccCity__c}"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="contractStreet" label="以下の住所" name="contractstreet" value="{!v.contract.NewAccStreet__c}"/>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Save Button -->
        <lightning:button label="申請する" onclick="{!c.createDDD}" variant="brand" class="slds-m-top_medium"/>
<!-- succes message -->
```

Controller.js

```
({
init: function(component, event, helper) {
    // 取引先の初期値取得
    helper.getAccountInfo(component, event);
},
createDDD: function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.createContractRecord(component);
    alert('OK!');
    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
}
})
```

Helper.js

```
({
getAccountInfo : function(component, event) {
    // Account ID
    var accountId = component.get("v.recordId");
    //alert(accountId);

    // Apex
    //var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
    var action = component.get("c.getChangeAccount");
    action.setParams({
        "accountId": accountId
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        var state = data.getState();
        //alert(state);
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            // Lightning側の変数『account』にApexからreturnされた結果をセット
            //component.set("v.account", data.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.contract", data.getReturnValue());
            //alert('ok');
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
        }
    });
    // Send action off to be executed
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
createContractRecord : function(component){
    var newContract = component.get("v.contract");
    console.log('newContract = ' + newContract);
    this.saveAAA(component,newContract,function(a){
        console.log('a = '+a); 
    });
},
saveAAA : function(component,contract,callback){
    var action = component.get("c.saveContract");
    console.log('saveAAA' + contract);
    action.setParams({
        "contract" : contract
    });
    if(callback){
        action.setCallback(this,callback);
    }
    alert('AAA');
    console.log('enqueueAction');
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Contoller.apxc

```
public class StoreChangeController {


@AuraEnabled
public static Account getAccount(Id accountId) {
    // Perform isAccessible() checks here
    return [SELECT Name,Furigana__c,StoreNickName__c,BillingPostalcode,BillingState,BillingCity,BillingStreet,Phone FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Contract__c getChangeAccount(Id accountId) {
    //レコードＩＤから店舗情報取得
    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Name,Furigana__c,StoreNickName__c,BillingPostalcode,BillingState,BillingCity,BillingStreet,Phone FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];

    //Contractの対応する項目にset
    Contract__c contract = new Contract__c();
    contract.NewAccName__c = accList[0].Name;
    contract.NewAccRuby__c = accList[0].Furigana__c;
    contract.NewAccNickname__c = accList[0].StoreNickName__c;
    contract.NewAccPostalcode__c = accList[0].BillingPostalcode;
    contract.NewAccState__c = accList[0].BillingState;
    contract.NewAccCity__c = accList[0].BillingCity;
    contract.NewAccStreet__c = accList[0].BillingStreet;
    contract.NewAccPhone__c = accList[0].Phone;
    return contract;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Contract__c saveContract(Contract__c contract) {
    contract.RecordTypeId= '012N0000000agxZIAQ';
    contract.AccountId__c= 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';        
    insert contract;
    return contract;
}
}
```

console.log
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91009/discussion-on-question-by-yuko-kisa9-why-doesnt-create-record-from-lightning-co).